# Finding pattern using in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a couple of strings and I want them to be transformed like shown below

In the first two examples `"` is included in the input string.
But `"` does not comes always with the input string as shown in last two examples.

Basically I need the string between `|"` and `"|` or string between first and last occurrence of `|`

Can someone please let me know how to find the match for the output string that I need which will work for all of these strings? I am trying to code these in C#.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Seems `[A-Z0-9]+\|\d+\|[01]` would work

Comment: match `^[^|]+\|"?|"?\|$` and replace with empty string `""`

Comment: Remove all quotes from the string and then drop the first 10 characters and the last one. `text = text.Replace("\"", ""); text = text.Substring(10, text.Length - 11)`

Answer (score 0):

I would propose an alternative to regex. Simply using [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) and [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_):

```
List<string> input = new List<string>
{
    "501000061|\"B084PD449Q|2088|1\"|",
    "504000585|\"B000NSIAG0|3115|0\"|",
    "508000036|B084S1FVH5|42|1|",
    "504000584|B000NSIAG0|3115|0|"
};

foreach (var element in input)
{
    string transformed = element.Substring(10, element.Length - 11)
                                .Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(transformed);
}
```

Output:

> `B084PD449Q|2088|1`
> `B000NSIAG0|3115|0`
> `B084S1FVH5|42|1`
> `B000NSIAG0|3115|0`

Answer (score -1):

`^[0-9]{9}\|"?([A-Z0-9]){10}\|([0-9]){2,}\|([0-9])"?\|$`

This regex is a bit more rigid than the ones already proposed based on the input examples that you've provided.

I suggest you look into non-regex solutions that have already been pointed out, however, if you absolutely must use regex here's how to do it in C# for this example.

```
  var pattern = @"^[0-9]{9}\|"?([A-Z0-9]){10}\|([0-9]){2,}\|([0-9])"?\|$";
  var replacement = "$1|$2|$3";
  var input = "501000061|\"B084PD449Q|2088|1\"|";
  var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one without regex:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inp = "504000585|\"B000NSIAG0|3115|0\"|";
        
        var res = string
            .Join("|", inp.Split(new []{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1))
            .Replace("\"", "");
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/i39XUY

```
B000NSIAG0|3115|0
```